# Asp 4 Async Task how to Convert NET 4.5 to NET4

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to transform the following code in NET4.0 
How Can I do it ? Please give me soeme help 
I only have VS 2010 and cannot change version of NET (stick with 4.0 version)
I have tried to convert the second method as bellow but it doesn't work on

```
   Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Video>>> GetVideosAsync()
        {
            var allVideosTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<Video>>>();
            foreach (var url in sources)
            {
                allVideosTasks.Add(DownloadDataAsync(url));
            }
            var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();


            var allVideos = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                allVideosTasks.ToArray(), result =>
         {
             int element = result.Count();
             Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, Thread={1} (ContinueWhenAny): number element = {2}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, element);
             var resu = result[0].Result;
         }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, context);

            return (Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Video>>>)allVideos;
        }


/*********     CODE NET4.5 ***********/
   public Task<ActionResult> Async()
    {
     var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     var data = GetVideosAsync();
     sw.Stop();
     ViewBag.Elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
     return View("~/views/home/index.cshtml", data);
    }
    async Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Video>>> GetVideoAsync()
    {
     var allVideos = new List<IEnumerable<Video>>();
     foreach (var url in sources) 
     {
      allVideos.Add(await DownloadAsync(url)); // downloading content from internet 
     }
    }
```

Comment: are you going from 4.0 to 4.5?

Comment: I'm not sure, but for .NET 4.0 you should look for asynchronous controllers.

Answer (score 0):

without re-writing the code completely, you could install the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package through nuget.  http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

> This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords. This package also includes Task-based extension methods that allow using some of the existing asynchronous APIs with the new language keywords.
>
> Supported Platforms:
>
> - .NET Framework 4 (with KB2468871)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below for the .NET 4.5 version. In your `Async` method you need to `await` the 
result of `GetVideosAsync` in order to have the complete list of videos, so method needs to be marked as `async` as well.

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Async()
   {
      var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      var data = await GetVideosAsync();
      sw.Stop();
      ViewBag.Elapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
     return View("~/views/home/index.cshtml", data);     
   }

    async Task<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Video>>> GetVideosAsync()
    {
        var allVideosTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<Video>>>();
        foreach (var url in sources)
        {
           allVideosTasks.Add(DownloadDataAsync(url));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(allVideosTasks.ToArray());       

        return allVideosTasks.Select(x => x.Result);
    }
```